# Apply Function to every cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have Terz-spectra data from acoustic measurements and I want to calculate the overall level. The values for each Terz-band are in decibel. Therefor the calculation formula is a bit lengthy. It would be L_overall=10*log10(10^(L_a/10)+10^(L_b/10)+10^(L_c/10)+10^(L_d/10)...).

As there are many frequencies, I don't want to write the whole formula by hand. I also don't want to use another column to do the inner calculation (10^(x/10)) before doing the outer calculation (10*log10(x+y+z+...)). So I wonder if there is a function in Excel that allows to apply a calculation on each cell like there is in Matlab for instance (cellfun, arrayfun).

I hope to end up with something similar like L_overall=10*log10(10^(B10:B80/10) which would allow me to do all the calculation in simply one cell.

Addition:
I have forgotten to say that I want the terz-data unaltered. I don't want to change that as I have to use it to plot that spectrum. So ideally I want all the work done in only one cell. I could do that by the lengthy formula, but it would take quite some time to type that for all frequencies.

Of course I could simply use another column and do the math there but that seems also inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the formula would be something like this:

```
=10*LOG(SUM(INDEX(10^(B10:B80/10),)),10)
```

Or this:

```
=10*LOG(SUMPRODUCT(10^(B10:B80/10)),10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but you could do 10^(L_a/10) for one cell, then click and drag the lower right corner to make that run for all cells. 
Then create another cell which takes 10*log10 of the SUM of those cells.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to insert a specific formula in a bunch of cells you could use this:

```
For Each rCell In Application.Selection
      rCell.Formula = "=10*log10(10^(L_a/10)+10^(L_b/10)+10^(L_c/10)+10^(L_d/10)...)"
Next rCell
```

Simply select all the cells in which you want to insert the formula and then run the sub. Make sure your formula is valid.