# Excel: Apply function to each cell inside formula

Tags: excel, range, formula

I am trying to devise a non-vba Excel function which checks each cell in multiple ranges for different parameters and then returns the number of applicable occurrences. My specific problem occurs when applying the HOUR function to a range of date-cells and counting how many of these cells are equal to a certain hour.

To clarify, in VBA I would write something like (please assume that column A contains dates):

```
Sub tester33()
Dim r As Range
Dim c
Dim a As Integer
Set r = Range("A1:A10")
a = 0
For Each c In r
    If (Hour(c) = 5) Then 'time is 5 am, other if conditions are omitted
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next c
MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

What I would like to have working is

```
=COUNTIF(HOUR(A:A);"=5")
```

My search so far returned nada. Please note that I found answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986102/apply-function-to-every-cell-in-excel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929254/excel-sum-of-a-column-but-apply-a-function-to-each-cell-before-sum), that unfortunately won't work for nonmathematical Excel functions.
I hope this isn't a completely trivial problem, as I am new to in-sheet formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative (non-array) formula is to use

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A:A)=5))`

which doesn't require committing the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It's ultimately a matter of preference.

Also, if your data doesn't stretch the entire length of column A, consider using only the range occupied by data (e.g. `A1:A50` instead of `A:A`), as Excel then doesn't have to iterate through blank cells, which can clunk things up.

Comment: TotsieMae and @Mrig both solved my Problem. Thank you to both. Restricting the range is a good suggestion too, which can always be recommended when facing problems with multiple cells.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I tend to use absolute references the majority of the time, except where relative references are needed. It's usually easier to prevent an issue before it happens than it is to try and figure out how to fix it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=SUM((HOUR(A1:A50)=5)*1)
```

or

```
=SUM(--(HOUR(A1:A50)=5))
```

Both are array formulas so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Change `A1:A50` to your data range.